# Is there a way to iterate through a hash with index values?

Tags: ruby, indexing, hash, iteration, key-value

I am writing a program to “correct” a current hash that I have. I have a hash who’s key-value pairs are "off" by just one. This is the incorrect hash:

```
wrong_hash = {:a => "banana", :b => "cabbage", :c => "dental_floss", :d => "eel_sushi”}
```

:c needs to be paired to “cabbage”,
:b needs to be paired to “banana”
etc

This is what I have so far. I am having trouble creating the variable `new_item`

```
def hash_correct(hash)
 correct_hash = {}

 hash.each do |key, item|
 new_item = 
  correct_hash << hash[key] = new_item
end

return correct_hash

end
```

NOTE: My interest is not so much to just get the correct answer, and I understand there are other ways to go about it (sort, while loop, etc) I just want to know if there is a way to include an index variable in my block. Something like |key, item, index|

I am a newbie so any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: What is the right hash pairs rule?

Comment: @Ilya Essentially whoever built the original hash was "one off" for every pair. So the value at index 0 "banana" really should be the value for index 1 (:b). And the value at index 1 "cabbage" should really be paired to index 2 at key :c

Comment: While you raise a valid question, the more ruby-esque solution to this problem doesn't involve explicit iteration, but instead using `map` as so: `wrong_hash.map{|k, v| [k.succ, v]}.to_h`

Comment: @user12341234 Thank you for your answer, this is a great way to go about it, and very ruby-esque indeed. In this case it works perfectly. But if the person really butchered the original hash, and wrote the keys as: :1st :2nd :3rd (or something similar), then this wouldn't work right?

Comment: What happens to value at index 0? Will its wrong key remain there or you will get rid of first key-value pair from hash altogether?

Comment: @WandMaker Good point. For index 0, key :a, we can just assign a value of nil.

Comment: @AljoshaNovakovic that's correct, my example is just a simple demonstration of how map can be applied to your problem. For other more complex transformations the contents of the map block body need to be modified.

Comment: @AljoshaNovakovic What will be the key for `"eel_sushi”` in  your example after moving stuff around?  Can you post desired output for your example?

Comment: Technically no key associated with this particular input. But the idea would be that the key for "eel-sushi" would be :e (the next key to come up). So I wanted to create a method that can "correct" even an incorrect hash with a thousand key-value pairs. 

But for this particular example the output should be: 
{:a => nil, :b => "banana", :c => "cabbage", :d => "dental_floss"}

Comment: When you are asked for clarification it's generally best to edit your answer rather than elaborating in comments. As it is, anyone reading your question (me included) must read through all the comments to understand it. That should not be necessary. You should also show your desired result (a hash) for `wrong_hash` (right after `wrong_hash`). That alone tells the reader what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) method, which for a hash would be used like this:

```
hash.each_with_index { |(k, v), i| ... }
```

However, you could solve your particular problem using

```
wrong_hash.keys.drop(1).zip(wrong_hash.values).to_h
# => {:b=>"banana", :c=>"cabbage", :d=>"dental_floss"}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but awesome thank you for this one!

Answer (score 1):

`each_cons`is nice for this:

```
wrong_hash = {:a => "banana", :b => "cabbage", :c => "dental_floss", :d => "eel_sushi"}

right_hash = {}
wrong_hash.each_cons(2){|(_, v1),(k2, _)| right_hash[k2] = v1}
p right_hash # => {:b=>"banana", :c=>"cabbage", :d=>"dental_floss"}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about .each_cons

Answer (score 0):

```
values = wrong_hash.values.unshift(nil)
  #=> [nil, "banana", "cabbage", "dental_floss", "eel_sushi"] 
wrong_hash.merge(wrong_hash) { values.shift }
  #=> {:a=>nil, :b=>"banana", :c=>"cabbage", :d=>"dental_floss"}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block (`{ values.shift }`) to determine the value of each key shared by both hashes being merged, which here is all keys.